# 2 column layout with header and footer

Tags: html, css

This seems so basic, yet every person has a round-about way of doing it and I can never get a clean and working solution.

My wanted design is:

[image]

Where the left column has a min-width of 640px  and the right column is fluid.
The footers is always at the bottom and the 2 columns always expand all the way to the footer.

Techniques I have applied are a absolute footer and then various techniques of trying to get the 2 columns to be equal is height, but I can't figure out how to get them to expand all the way down to the footer.

The CSS has to be IE10+ compatible (but IE9 preferred)

Here is my attempt, which t**he columns are not fitting 100% height  and also resizing the browser does weird things with the header and footer. I want it so if the browser width goes below 1280px then it should get scroll bars**

https://jsfiddle.net/uj4yekat/

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <header class="header">

    </header><!-- .header-->

    <div class="middle">

        <div class="container">
            <main class="content">

          </main><!-- .content -->
        </div><!-- .container-->

        <aside class="left-sidebar">
            <nav class="nav">
          </nav>
      </aside><!-- .left-sidebar -->

    </div><!-- .middle-->

    <footer class="footer">

    </footer><!-- .footer -->

</div><!-- .wrapper -->



.nav {
  background: #d2d3d5;
  height: 60px;

}

.header {
    height: 30px;
    background: #1378a9;
    text-align: right;
    color: white;
}


.middle {
    border-left: 640px solid #B5E3FF;
    position: relative;
}
.middle:after {
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    content: '';
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: -100%;
}
.content {
    padding: 0 20px;
    padding-bottom:40px; 
}


.left-sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 640px;
    position: relative;
    background: #ebf2f5;
    left: -640px;
    min-height: 700px;
    border-right: 1px solid #1378a9;
}


.footer {
    height: 40px;
    background: #1378a9;
    text-align: right;
    color: white;
     position:absolute;
     bottom:0;
     width: 100%;

}
```

Comment: The right side is doing weird things too: https://jsfiddle.net/avcjymLn/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a height 100% you need a parent and a child in this case the body is the parent, so let's start with that

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<header></header>
<main>
  <aside></aside>
  <section></section>
</main>
<footer></footer>
```

CSS

```
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
header {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
}

main {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 680px;
  position: relative;
}

main aside {
  width: 680px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: peru;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Then you have some unnecessary divs and CSS classes defined. Basically, the trick is in the body and HTML, I hope this approach works for you.

[Pen With Solution](https://codepen.io/AlejandroMAL/pen/JrrVRx)

Comment: when reducing the width, weird things happen to the header: https://imgur.com/a/XX1a8

Comment: Sorry didn't realize you asked for scrollbar when the screen is less than 1280. Check once. https://codepen.io/AlejandroMAL/pen/JrrVRx

Answer (score 0):

if IE9 is to be involved, then `display:table;` only remains aside position:absolute.

example

```css
html,
body,
.wrapper,
.tble {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper,
.tble {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tbcell,
.content,
.left-sidebar {
  display: table-cell;
}
header,
footer,
.middle {
  display: table-row;
  height: 0;
  background: lightblue;
}
.container,
aside,
main {
  padding: 1em;
}
.middle {
  height: 100%;
  background: lightgreen;
}
.tble {
  direction: rtl;
  border-top: solid;
  border-bottom: solid;
}
.tble > * {
  direction: ltr;
}
aside {
  border-right: solid;
  width: 648px;
  background:pink
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="header">
    <div class="container tbcell">header<br/> of any heights</div>
  </header>
  <!-- .header-->
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="container tble">
      <main class="content">content</main>
      <!-- .content -->
    <!-- .container-->
    <aside class="left-sidebar">
      <nav class="nav">nav on <b>left</b>-sidebar</nav>
    </aside>
    <!-- .left-sidebar -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .middle-->
  <footer class="footer">
<div class="container tbcell">footer<br/> of any heights</div>
</footer><!-- .footer -->
</div>
<!-- .wrapper -->
```

IE8 should also understand the table-layout display.
https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/dVVEOO